# Setting $HOME in PowerShell

Tags: windows-7, windows, powershell, environment-variables

How do I change my default home directory to "C:\Users\khornsby" for every time I open powershell?

I am running Windows 7. Below is info about the state of my environment.

```
Windows PowerShell
Copyright (C) 2009 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

PS P:\> cd ~
PS P:\> echo $HOME
P:\
PS P:\> HOME="C:\Users\khornsby"
The term 'HOME=C:\Users\khornsby' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet,
function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or
if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:25
+ HOME="C:\Users\khornsby" 

PS P:\> Set-Variable HOME "C:\Users\khornsby"
Set-Variable : Cannot overwrite variable HOME because it is read-only or
constant.
At line:1 char:13
+ Set-Variable 

PS P:\> dir env:home*

Name                           Value
----                           -----
HOMEPATH                       \
HOMEDRIVE                      P:
HOMESHARE                      \\fileserv\khornsby$


PS P:\>
```

Comment: How did your format your post? I like the way what you typed is highlighted.

Comment: I used the `<kbd>` tag.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The variable is read only by default, but can be removed with the `-Force` switch to Remove-Variable. To make your change persistent across sessions, you can make a profile file which is much like a `.bashrc` (For bash on Linux) except for Powershell.

In your Documents directory (normally `C:\Users\YOUR_USERNAME_HERE\documents`) for your user account, create a **WindowsPowerShell** folder (named exactly like that) if one does not already exist. Inside the folder, create a text file called **profile.ps1** (**ensure it's not profile.ps1.txt**).

Inside the file, place anything you want executed when you open Powershell.

example:

```
Write-Host "Hi John, welcome back!"
Remove-Variable -Force HOME
Set-Variable HOME "C:\Users\khornsby"
```

result:

[image]

Comment: You can also have the script run on startup from a shortcut, pointing to:  `%SystemRoot%\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -NoExit -ExecutionPolicy bypass -File C:\foo\profile.ps1`

Comment: I tried this, and it does successfully change the value of $HOME. But "cd ~" still stubbornly switches to the original location.

Comment: @Weeble, see my answer for overriding the ~ shortcut.

Comment: This does not work when opening a terminal in VS Code.

Answer (score 14):

To address @Weeble 's concern about the `~` shortcut:

```
$HOMEDRIVE = "C:\"
$HOMEPATH = "Users\" + $env:username

# Set and force overwrite of the $HOME variable
Set-Variable HOME "$HOMEDRIVE$HOMEPATH" -Force

# Set the "~" shortcut value for the FileSystem provider
(get-psprovider 'FileSystem').Home = $HOMEDRIVE + $HOMEPATH
```

See [here](http://www.beefycode.com/post/The-Difference-Between-~-and-$home.aspx) for the distinction between ~ and $HOME

Comment: it's worth adding `cd $HOME` at the end, so the shell will start in that location and will be all set for use :)

Answer (score 7):

To change from within Windows, try the following:

- Pin PowerShell to the taskbar.
- Right click the PowerShell icon on the taskbar.
- Right click 'Windows PowerShell' and select 'Properties'.
- Within the 'Properties' window, go to the 'Shortcut' tab
  and change the 'Start in:' field to your desired starting directory. (Example: `C:\Users\username\Desktop`).
- Click 'OK'.
- Launch PowerShell from the taskbar.

  [image: taskbar]

  [image: Properties window]

Comment: not works when select 'run as administrator'

Comment: this was the only thing that worked for me

Answer (score 6):

Even easier ... open up advanced system settings ...

```
 C:\> systempropertiesadvanced
```

Add a new system variable named HOME with the path to your profile

[image]

Restart explorer or log out and back in ...

```
PS C:\> $Env:home 
---
```

Comment: This doesn't do what the question asks. This sets the environment variable $env:HOME, not the Powershell variable $HOME. The Powershell variable $HOME appears to be derived from the environment variables $env:HOMEDRIVE and $env:HOMEPATH at the time the Powershell process starts. It is $HOME that determines the behaviour of "cd ~".

Comment: Sorry, that last statement isn't quite true. $HOME and the behaviour of "cd ~" both appear to match the values of the HOMEDRIVE and HOMEPATH environment variables when the Powershell process starts. Subsequently changing any of these variables/environment variables appears to have no effect on the directory chosen by "cd ~".

Comment: Works fine for me.... I don't know what you're doing differently.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `help about_profiles` to see more details about this.
Do not forget to sign your script.

Comment: `help` from what application?

Comment: @kzh: PowerShell